# Switch the php version in my Server

Tags: php, linux

Before I use make installed my `php7.1`, but now I use yum installed the `php7.0` in my CentOS7.2 server.

Now I want change the using php version `php7.1` for `php7.0`.

how to do with this?

the `php7.1` location is `/usr/local/php-7.1.16`,

and I execute the

```
# whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/local/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

when I use

```
# php -v
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2018 05:31:51) ( ZTS )
```

How can I use the `php7.0` replace of `php7.1`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: sudo a2dismod php7.1 -> this is disable php7.1
then
sudo a2enmod php7.0 -> this is to enable php7.0
then
sudo service apache2 restart -> to restart your apache service

Comment: there is no package for `yum install -y a2dismod`

Comment: ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d -> to see your repo, yum install yum-utils -> to install yum-config-manager, yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70 -> enable your repo